# Magnific Popup: Make title over image

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I want to use [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) with the title above the image.

I found in the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) under **Image Type** the property *markup* and I was able to put the title above the image if I use this code

then I get this result

[image]

However, I want that the title should not be larger then the image. Here is how it looks when I do not change the markup:

[image]

How can I prevent the title to set the width of the window? I want the window to meet the width of the image.

```js
$('.grid').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  type: 'image',
  image: {
    markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
      '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
      '<div class="mfp-title"></div>' +
      '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +
      '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
      '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <a class="popup-link" href="ENTE-611.jpg" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" title='A lot of text - A lot of text - - A lot of textext -  - A lot of text -  - A lot of text -  - A lot of text -  - A lot of text -  - A lot of text -  - A lot of text -  '>
    <img class='link img-link' src="ENTE-611s.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 `<figcaption>` tag and wrap up mfp-title in it then surround the whole container mfp-img div using  `<figure>` tag like this

```
image: {
   markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
             '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
             '<figure>'+
             '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +  
             '<figcaption>'+
               '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
                 '<div class="mfp-title"></div>' +
                 '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>' +
               '</div>'+
             '</figcaption>'+
             '</figure>' +
           '</div>'
}
```